# redshift_connector: TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to connect to a Redshift Cluster using the redshift_connector library in python.

The cluster is publicly accessible
The associated security group has my hosts IP address added to Inbound rules: Redshift, port 5439 and Whole inbound traffic. Same goes for outgoing traffic.

This is how I try to make the connection:

```
conn = redshift_connector.connect(host='******.******.eu-central 1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
                              database='*******',
                              port=5439,
                              user='awsuser',
                              password='**********')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error:

I also have to add the inbound rule to allow connections to redshift from 0.0.0.0/0